# Paint on C# сохранение + рисование

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем. Хотел узнать а как можно реализовать сохранение картинки + то что я на ней нарисовал, сама функция для сохранения реализована, а как к ней прибавить то что рисовал я сам???  Заранее спасибо! 
Ф-я рисования

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(pressed)
            {
                PrevPoint = CurrentPoint;
                CurrentPoint = e.Location;
                color_mix();
            }
        }
```

Функция сохранения

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width,pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
                {
                    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                    sfd.FileName = "1111";
                    sfd.DefaultExt = "jpg";
                    sfd.Filter = "ImageFiles(*.BMP, *.JPG, *.GIF, *.PNG)|*.bmp,*.jpg,*.gif,*.png | AllFiles(*.*) | *.* ";
                    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
                    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
```

Выдает ошибку при сейве

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида.
   в System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   в System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   в Paint.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\Paint\Paint\Form1.cs:строка 75
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать вашу функцию сохранения так:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width,
                               pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
{
   pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
   bmp.Save(yourfilename, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Ошибку выбрасывает

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka если вы просто взяли и скопировали код, то работать не будет. Нужно вместо `yourfilename` прописать корректный путь к расположению на диске.

Comment: изменял,  посмотри в описании

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka описание ошибки хотелось бы увидеть.

Comment: @Exoudium Выложил

Comment: Ошибку выложил. Проявляется при сейве